# actionbar cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: sdk

Compiling error when build project in 
sdk\extras\android\support\samples\Support4Demos

1. Eclipse, import existing code into workspace, ...\sdk\extras\android\support\samples\Support4Demos
2. Right click on the imported project -> build path -> configure build path, add the jar file named "android-support-v4.jar" in sdk\extras\android\support\v4
3. Build the project, then I have 196 errors. Most part is "ActionBar cannot be resolved to a type"

I have also tried to import android-support-v13.jar, result is the same. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue could be solved by changing the compiler compliance level to 1.6 by **Project->Properties->Java Compiler**