# ActionBar cannot be resolved as a type

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I'm trying to learn how to make tabs in an android app. Reading through tutorials, I had the idea that we should implement the ActionBar.TabListener (to inherit the onTabSelected and other methods ) and getting fragments involved (so I can swipe the fragments), like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener
```

However, Eclipse insists on telling me that ActionBar cannot be resolved as a type, and the suggested solusions is to create the interface, which is not helpful, thank you guys for your help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625890/actionbar-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type

Comment: Sorry but the compliance level is already level 1.6, still didn't work @MortezaSoleimani

Comment: Check for updates & change workspace.

Comment: @WB Updates in what? the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem of this, and it will give you an idea just for trying.

Add `import android.app.ActionBar;`
If you cannot import this package, then I think you have a problem with the Eclipse settings.

Another important thing, know that **ActionBar.TabListener** is deprecated by the latest API level 21, documentation @ [ActionBar.TabListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.TabListener.html)

Comment: thank you for your help, I walked with your advice, and the error I posted is fixed. However, now the TabListener is causing another error:
Class requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.app.ActionBar.TabListener

Comment: That should be easy to fix. I don't use Eclipse. It says if you want to use ActionBar, you need to raise the min API level to at least 11, which is reasonable level. This is probably set in the Ecliple compliler settings. If you don't know how, then post another question.

Comment: @samDroid, for our benefits, add/explain your fix in your original question. Maybe we will learn something from your problem. You did attract few people. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know its Bit late but hope someone will find it useful.

try importing ActionBar

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
```

if you can import it then try to implent tablistener like this

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements android.app.ActionBar.TabListener {
```

worked for me.